# OpenJDK Java 7 missing from "Open With" under file Properties

Tags: 13.04, launcher, java, minecraft, openjdk

Ok.  I have read through probably two-dozen posts and articles, and still can't seem to find an answer.  I have installed OpenJDK-7 and am trying to set it as the default to open .jar files (specifically, I'm trying to set it as the default for minecraft.jar, freshly downloaded from the minecraft.org site).

I am running the 64-bit version of Ubuntu 13.04 (fresh install), and installed OpenJDK through the Software Center.  Everything looks to be fine, OpenJDK shows up in the /usr/share/applications directory.  If I right-click on minecraft.jar I see "OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime" as an option under the "Open With" context menu.  That's fine.  It launches the minecraft launcher, checks for updates, and I can fire up the game.  The problem is, if I go to "Properties" and then to the "Open With" tab, OpenJDK is nowhere to be found in the list of options.  I want to set it up as the default for .jar files so I can set up a launcher to drop into the unity launcher.

I have also used gedit in a terminal window to change the "defaults.list" file in the /applications directory to use openjdk-7-java.desktop for both jar and java-archive.

No matter what I try, the outcome is always the same: I can launch it if I right-click > open with > OpenJDK...     but I cannot set OpenJDK as the default for .jar files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to add the option in the tab of the *Open With* menu. 
But to create a shortcut for the dash, you can use the *alacarte* application.

[image]

Then, you could drag-and-drop the shorcut to add it to your main menu.

Answer (score 0):

If You have Ubuntu Tweak, you can create asociation in card File Types Manager
Select line "Archive Java" and change the record by double click:
Add > Use own command > type "/usr/bin/java -jar " and press enter.
After that you can easily run java app by double-clicking on it.

Happy clicking!